# How can I replace the prefix "0" to "+49"

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

How can I replace the prefix "0" to "+49" of a string in Lua?

Example in sed:

```
echo 030111 | sed "s/^0/\+49/" -> +4930111
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) with the same anchor `^`: `string.gsub("030111", "^0", "+49")`. This returns `+4930111`.

Comment: Ninja'd just as I was hitting submit! Ha!

Comment: I thought I sensed someone else typing the same answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using gsub:

```
string.gsub("030111", "^0", "+49")
```